# How to cap multiple holes in a model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges

Is there a way to quickly fill holes instead of selecting each of edge loop and then fill it ??

for example this sphere
[image]

Is there an one click function to cap those holes without selecting them one by one to manually fill them ??

Comment: There is a function called "Fill Holes". If you increase the "Sides" number in the left bottom corner pop-up menu it will fill every holes with one face. Of course you have to select everything before use it.

Comment: it doesn't seems to work fine for holes with more than one face missing though... ctrl F > Grid Fill may be useful sometimes, but for some holes I guess you need to do it manually (there might be some addons for this kind of tasks)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)